# Glide listener doesn't work

Tags: android, callback, imageview, android-glide

I'm using Glide to load images and I added a listener to know when resource is ready or if there was an error of any type:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.glide_placeholder)
    // use dontAnimate and not crossFade to avoid a bug with custom views
    .dontAnimate()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            // do something
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            // do something
            return true;
         }
    })
    .into(mCustomImageView);
```

The app never runs inside `onResourceReady` or `onException` but if I remove the listener and let the async download without a callback, it runs correctly:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.glide_placeholder)
    // use dontAnimate and not crossFade to avoid a bug with custom views
    .dontAnimate()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(mCustomImageView);
```

I tried also with `GlideDrawableImageViewTarget` instead of listener to receive callbacks but app runs inside `onLoadStarted` but never runs inside `onLoadCleared`, `onLoadFailed` and `onResourceReady`.

Comment: You're saying the listener's onException and onResourceReady methods aren't called? Returning true from those methods will prevent the Target from being called, but they should always be called for the listener regardless.

Comment: I think you need to call `submit` in order to initiate it to start loading

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with ImageView's visibility if it's invisible or gone. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/618

Comment: omg, I was transitioning from Picasso to Glide but this was unexpected. Glide does't call the callback if the view is still invisible :(

Answer (score 29):

Here's one way to do it:

```
        Glide.with(context).load(...)
                .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                    override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        //TODO handle error images while loading photo
                        return true
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        //TODO use "resource" as the photo for your ImageView
                        return true
                    }

                }).submit()
```

Comment: Huh that's weird, adding .submit() seems to have fixed the issue on my end. Any idea what change was made that causes .load(...) to no longer work directly? The docs are coming up blank for me.

Comment: I think you need to initiate it at some point, because without a target (or just telling it to do it), it doesn't know when to perform the operation.

Comment: i can't write .into(imageview) after .submit()

Comment: @karthikkolanji You have the listener. Do it in `onResourceReady`

Comment: Finally, a Kotlin example. This was much needed.

Answer (score 11):

Ran into same issue. Having onResourceReady return false did the trick for me.

Comment: @styler1972 I've added my code, if you wish to look. Seems to work fine on my case.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to change the return of `onResourceReady` and `onLoadFailed` from true to false.

It works for me on `glide 4.9.1`.

if you look at RequestListener comments you should understand.

Answer (score 6):

Ran into same issue because the width and height of my `ImageView` were 0,0 ( both `layout_width` and `layout_height` were set to `wrap_content` with no Image was set on `ImageView` initially). giving `ImageView` a default width and height solved my issue.

Comment: Better provide coding to show how the problem solved.

Comment: Same issue because imageView visibility was `.GONE`.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin way to use Glide with listener**

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(image_url)
                .listener(object : com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener<Drawable> {
                    override fun onLoadFailed(
                        e: GlideException?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Drawable?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                        dataSource: DataSource?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        img_product_banner.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        return false
                    }

                }).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(img_product_banner)
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
try {
        Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(characterDB.url)
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Bitmap> {
                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Bitmap?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Bitmap>?,
                    dataSource: DataSource?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Bitmap>?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
            }
            )
            .submit()
    }
    catch (e : Exception)
    {
        Log.d("Excepion",e.message.toString())
    }
```