# Open Activity after Complete GIF loading using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide to load GIF image in splash screen.
After completion of GIF loading, I want to open next activity using Intent.

I tried below code,

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.image1).override(width, height).into(imageViewTarget);
```

and Glide Version : com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

But not able to find any help, please help to solve this.

Comment: Add listener to your glide then go your another activity after done. And make sure your image view is visible, otherwise glide has the issue with image visibility http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503327/glide-listener-doesnt-work.

Answer (score 2):

Just spent a couple hours trying to find a solution for this for Glide V4 and this is what I finally came across and it works perfect.
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/pull/3438

```
        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            resource.setLoopCount(1);
            resource.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                    //in your case start new Activity
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Simply superb, it worked like magic for me. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

put listner to handle this..

```
     Glide.with(this)
    .load(R.drawable.image1)
    .asGif()
    .override(width, height)
                 .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                       //AFTER LOAD OUT YOUR LOGIC
                                      //open next activity
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                })
     .into(imageViewTarget);
```

and make sure your imageview is always visible.
Hope this helps..

Comment: With this Glide Version : com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0', if I use asGif() It's not work. It will generate an error in code.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view,what you want is to start another activity when the **GIF Animation** finished rather than the gif is just load into your ImageView.
In such case, you'd better measure how long it will take to finish the gif animation and make it a local variable.In order to make sure the gif animation is complete,it's better to make the time a bit longer than the animation costs.
Then do it like this.

```
long gifAnimationTime = 1000;// A bit more than the gif animation,you can ajust this to your situation.
Glide.with(this)
        .load(R.drawable.image1)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // start your activity here.
                    }
                }, gifAnimationTime);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(imageViewTarget);
```

I got something new.Try this：

```
    Movie movie = Movie.decodeByteArray(gifdata,offset,length);
    long period = movie.duration();
```

Comment: No, I don't want to provide fixed time. Will get time form gif then it will help.

Comment: You'd better known that gif is made of several frames and keeps looping.There seems no way to measure its single period in android.

Comment: If you have to do this,you can try to make the gif into seperate pictures using **GifSplitter**.Then it is easy to create an animation with the pictures   .

Comment: It will take more time because Split and Generate new gif in splash screen, we have to provide max 6sec not more then that.

Comment: I modified my answer above.Have a try.

Comment: Not work, because in this we have to provideByteArray.

Comment: Due to my limited network,it seems difficult for me to join the chat.The page shows "Loading discussion between ... and ... Just a second." for quite a long time. You can transfer it into ByteArray by this: Glide.with(context).load(url).asBitmap().toBytes().listener(......)

Comment: If I convert in to Bitmap or in to Bytes Array then it will not work like a GIF.