# Glide - Cannot resolve method listener

Tags: android, android-glide

```
storageReference.child("ProfilePicture")
    .child(currUser.getUid())
    .getDownloadUrl()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            profilePicture = storageReference.child("ProfilePicture").child(currUser.getUid());
            Glide.with(getBaseContext())
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(profilePicture)
                    .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                    .into(profilePictures)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<URL, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, URL model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressDialogCreate.hide();
                            return false;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, URL model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressDialogCreate.hide();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
            profilePictures.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

I'm getting this error,

[image: I'm getting this error:]

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Post your glide dependency

Comment: compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

Comment: @Suto-MinyukusTamas update to latest version `compile com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0` and Change `GlideDrawable` to `Drawable` because in latest version There's no `GlideDrawable` any more.

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati If I do that, I get the same error for '.using(new FirebaseImageLoader())' and cannot resolve symbol 'StringSignature'

Comment: for FirebaseImageLoader I use {compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'}

Comment: @Suto-MinyukusTamas I have tried to solve your error..have a look at my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:-**

Use this dependency to use `GlideDrawable` method of `Glide` and `.using(new FirebaseImageLoader())` method of `FirebaseUi`

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

---

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(profilePicture)
                    .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                    .into(profilePictures)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<URL, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, URL model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressDialogCreate.hide();
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, URL model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressDialogCreate.hide();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

**Edit:-**

Try to apply listener like this.

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(profilePicture)
                .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(profilePictures) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> animation) {
                        super.onResourceReady(resource, animation);
                        //try to hide here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                        //try to hide here
                    }
                });
```

Comment: The problem was that I had the wrong order between the methods `into` and `listener` and I had to change the paramter type too ( `URL` to `StorageReference` ), but now even if the image is loaded or not, it doesn't call none of the functions

Comment: @Suto-MinyukusTamas so you are saying that your error **Cannot resolve method listener** and for `.using()` is resolved but it doesn't effect?

Comment: Yes, onException and onResourceReady are never called it doesn't matter if the image is loaded or not

Comment: @Suto-MinyukusTamas  `progressDialogCreate`  is a `ProgressDialog `??

Comment: @Suto-MinyukusTamas  if you are using `ProgressBar`  than try progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); and if you are using `ProgressDialog` than try to dismiss `progressDialog.dismiss();`

Comment: ProgressDialog, but the onResourceReady function is never called. I tried it with a Toast instead of the ProgessDialog but it doesn't show up.

Comment: @Suto-MinyukusTamas hey..check the updated answer. try to apply listener this way.

Comment: @Suto-MinyukusTamas that's great and welcome, if its helpful then accept my answer and upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong order between the methods. 
`into(profilePictures)` will return a variable of type `Target<GlideDrawable>`, but `listener` needs to be called by a `DrawableTypeRequest`. Switch the order between `into` and `listener` and it should work.

Comment: Well the error dissaperead, I had to change the parameter type too ( `URL` to `StorageReference`), but even if the image is loaded or not, it doesn't call none of the functions

Comment: How do you check to see if they are called?

Comment: The progressDialog doesn't dissapear, even if the image is loaded and after I have tried with a Toast but it doesn't show up

Comment: Ok, I think that the issue is that your imageview is hidden. If it is hidden, then the load doesn't start, hence no callback called. Check this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503327/glide-listener-doesnt-work

Comment: its not hidden `<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicture"        
        android:layout_width="100dp"               
        android:layout_height="100dp"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/powered_by_google_dark" />`

Comment: Then why do you call this `profilePictures.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`?

Comment: When I created the ImageView, I set it hidden in the xml file, but later I changed the code and I forget there that row in the java file. But it doesn't work even if I let there or I delete that row.

Comment: Did you tried other solutions from the link I provided? If the answer is yes, I think that you should open another question and ask that, because right now we are discussing something that is not related to the original question (which is solved now)

Answer (score 0):

`GlideDrawable` are **deprecated**, use listener like this.

```
            Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(item.getFriendUserPhotoUrl())
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        fullname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_default_photo);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fullname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
```